# onUserLocationUpdated does not enter in the function

Tags: flutter, mapbox-gl

I am trying to execute certain lines of code when the user's location is updated, for this I have been using onUserLocationUpdated, however, it never enters the function, also I have a path in the Android emulator and I can see the user's marker move. Here the code:

```
MapboxMap(
        accessToken: token,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          zoom: 15.0,
          target: LatLng(14.508, 46.048),
        ),
        onMapCreated: (MapboxMapController controller) async{

          final result = await acquireCurrentLocation();

          await controller.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdate.newLatLng(result),
          );

          await controller.addCircle(
            CircleOptions(
              circleRadius: 8.0,
              circleColor: '#006992',
              circleOpacity: 0.8,
              geometry: result,
              draggable: true,
            ),
          );
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        myLocationTrackingMode: MyLocationTrackingMode.Tracking,
        onUserLocationUpdated: (UserLocation userLocation){
          print("Updated"); //It should print this, but never does
        },
      )
```

Comment: Does it work with `google_maps_flutter` package?

Comment: @iDecode No, but for what I could see is pretty similar

Comment: You already solved this ?